# Django - Keeping the original method's work and add new custom validation 

Tags: python, django

This is supposed to be a Django-specific, but I guess it's Python anyway.

Basically, I don't want to override the work of the original method in the class I am inheriting (could be a Model class), but I'd like to add additional validation. **Is this possible?** Any hint?

```
class MyUserAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    def clean(self):
        // do some additional work even though it's cleaned by parent's clean method
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the [super](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) classes clean method:

```
def clean(self): 
    super(MyUserAdminForm, self).clean()
    # more cleaning
```

This is a common python thing to do when you subclass something and redefine functionaly but want to make sure you keep the super class functionality. Extremely common when you do an init method, as you always need to ensure the super class constructor gets called to set up the instance.

Comment: For the OP, note the gotcha with `super`: the first argument is the name of the *current* class.

Comment: @jdi Thanks. This is very helpful to know. I was thinking about the same thing, but I've only seen `__init__` being used. So I can do the same with any `clean_` method, or just happen to be any method :)

Comment: @User007: Ya pretty much. Like I said, the init one is super common so I am sure you have seen it. `super()` is a helper function for finding the right super class method to call. It is a smart way of doing `forms.ModelForm.clean(self)`. super figures out which class to call `clean` on for you.

Comment: A simple way to explain it is that `super(ClassName, self)` is a quick and easy way to reference the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
        message = forms.CharField()
        def clean_message(self):
                num_words = len(message.split())
                if num_words<4:
                        raise forms.ValidationError("Too short a message!")
                return message
```

This is the way you add a validation method on a field, and this does ensure that the default cleanup happens. There is no need to call the default cleanup method again.

Source: www.djangobook.com

How it works:

When is_valid() is called on the form object, the system looks for any methods in the class that begin with clean_ and ends with an attribute name. If they do, it runs them **after** running the default cleanup methods.

Comment: Thanks. I know this, but I don't think that will solve my problem. The default cleanup is wdiget specific. If it's a password field, it has its own default cleanup. BUt if you are inheriting from your own Form / ModelForm, and if you just put `clean_message` you will override the original method you defined in your parent class. That's the issue I was having.

Comment: `clean_<fieldname>()` is called **after** the default cleanup methods.